# Splunk cloud Http Event Collector not working

Tags: splunk

I created a free Splunk cloud account and trying to push data to the main index of Splunk cloud by exposing HTTP rest endpoints by following [splunk doc](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/6.6.3/Data/UsetheHTTPEventCollector)

but I am getting a timeout exception for below endpoint

```
curl -k  https://prd-p-f4txzc7qgv77.cloud.splunk.com:8088/services/collector/event -H "Authorization: Splunk 07944f24-c69e-42fc-af3c-14035bddb085" -d '{"event": "hello world"}'
```

Response :

```
curl: Failed to connect to prd-p-f4txzc7qgv77.cloud.splunk.com port 8088: Operation timed out
```

Please help someone how to push data to Splunk cloud instance index.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix `input-` to your url.

Your url should be `https://input-prd-p-f4txzc7qgv77.cloud.splunk.com:8088/services/collector/event`